# Updating a violin plot with Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, flask, seaborn, bokeh

**NOTE FROM BOKEH MAINTAINER**: The MPL compatibility layer in Bokeh was deprecated and removed a long time ago. Nothing in this question is relevant to any recent or future versions of Bokeh.

---

I have a a violin plot created with mpl and bokeh which uses a dataframe as a data source. Example: 
`ax = sns.violinplot(x="Week of", y="Total Time",data=df, palette="muted", split=False, scale="count", inner="box", bw=0.1)`

Then I create my plot with `plot = mpl.to_bokeh()`

The X axis are dates. I want to dynamically update this bokeh plot (the values being used on the x axis) when a user changes a slider widget. For example I have the slider: 
`beginSlider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Start Date", callback=callback)`

When the user changes the date on the slider I want the data source for the plot to be changed thus updating the dates on the xaxis of the plot. I am familiar with bokeh callbacks, however because the source for this plot is a dataframe and not a ColumnDataSource I can not figure out how to trigger a change for the data source/plot in a widget callback. Any thoughts?

Comment: The MPL compat layer does alot of conversion for you up front, to turn data that MPL expects into Bokeh data sources. My first comment is that updating mpl compat plots "in place" is probably not going to work well at all. You can certainly dig into the renderer list `plot.renderers` and then for each renderer find its `.data_source`. But to update it you'd need to recompute the new violin plot visual data yourself, by hand, which is probably not what you want. Best bet is to use a server app, put the plot in a container (e.g. `column`) and swap it out whole each (python server) callback.

Comment: So I thought I would be able to edit the dataframe and redraw the plot based off the new dataframe. I guess that's a lot of work digging into each data source. Not entirely sure what you meant by putting the plot in a container. Right now I have this running on server with Flask.

Comment: And by edit the dataframe I meant edit the DataSource that the dataframe became.

Comment: The dataframe becomes *several* data sources, that is the "problem". Seaborn *derives* lots of coordinates from the input data, there is not a 1-1 relationship. So everything has to be recomputed from scratch. In particular it has to be computed by actual python, not JS. Options: use a separate Bokeh server, or have a non-Bokeh slider trigger something in Flask to serve a whole new plot.

Comment: I also suggest coming by the project mailing list. SO is pretty terrible for iterative discussions that don't have a pat answer.

Comment: Alright thank you! I am going to look into both of those options

Comment: I am having some weird behavior with Bokeh server. Only the first window opened to access the localhost will work. The page won't load on all other attempts to navigate to localhost while the server is running.

Comment: That's unusual and not like anything I have experienced. Would require real investigation. Please come by the project public mailing list with details (versions, code to reproduce, exact steps you took, etc)